# How to use explicit wait on one element out of a list with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have HTML that (somehow) includes two elements with the same ID. Only one of them is clickable, and to identify the one I want to click, I am using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('someID')[1]
```

Now I want to convert this to an explicit wait. If there was only one element with that ID (or any selector), I would do this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someID')))
```

How do I convert that statement to identify the second item with that ID, not the first? The alternative is to use the full xpath of the element, but I thought finding the second element with the ID would be more stable.

Comment: You can still use xpath and leverage ID attribute in the xpath

Comment: since there are two elements with the same ID (unfortunate), this does not work, because it just picks the first element with that ID to begin the xpath with

Comment: You can select the one using the index. try the following xpath    //*[@id='someID'][2]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `element_to_be_clickable()` you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "someID")))[1].click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#someID")))[1].click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='someID']")))[1].click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: this gave me a standard `TimeoutException1`, as if the elements are not found. however `driver.find_elements_by_id('getDimension')` works perfectly.