# expected_conditions.elementS_to_be_clickable((By.TAGNAME,'a'))

Tags: selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition, tagname

I have some webscraping project where I have a code like this:

```
sleep(1)
meeting_link = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
meeting_link[25].click()
```

My question is, how can I use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
```

to return either all of the a tags or the 25th one.
Or do I just have to use sleep() instead.

Comment: Refer this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63061024/16452840)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent `WebDriverWait` command would be :

```
meeting_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
```

`meeting_link` is a list, you can click on `25th` web element, Just like you did above.